# Your Ruby version is 2.2.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to `bundle install` a ruby project in Git Bash but I'm getting the above message.

```
ruby -v
```

> ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i836-mingw32]

```
gem -v
```

> 2.3.0

New to Ruby so its really frustrating. I'm trying to do the project below 
http://www.viralrails.com/?p=25

Comment: Remove line `ruby '2.3.0'` from `Gemfile`, then rerun `bundle install`.

Comment: Don't do that. If your app depends on Ruby 2.3.0 this will be another problem. I posted an answer explaining step by step what must be done.

Comment: How did you install Ruby? Do you use a Ruby version manager like RVM or rbenv?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0)

Answer (score 20):

This happens because you are specifying a Ruby version in your Gemfile (2.3.0) and this version is not installed or is not the current or default version.

Don't remove the line ruby '2.3.0' as someone said above. You app may have dependencies to this version. Do the following:

**1)** Check if you have Ruby 2.3.0 installed. If you are using rvm this may be done by

```
rvm list
```

and if you are using rbenv by

```
rbenv versions
```

**2)** If you don't have this Ruby version in your list of installed versions, then install it by issuing the following command

```
rvm install 2.3.0
```

and if you are using rbenv by

```
rbenv install 2.3.0
```

**3)** If you already had Ruby 2.3.0 installed or completed step **2** above, enter your app directory and issue the following command

```
rvm use 2.3.0
```

and if you are using rbenv by

```
rbenv local 2.3.0
```

Then run

```
bundle install
```

and I believe things will be ok.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't think so. I just suggested things to correct his problem. But if it makes you feel great and smart downvoting a correct answer, feel free to do it.

Comment: This can be a correct answer, __only__ if OP use the rvm ruby manager.

Comment: Then why don't you post a correct answer using other version manager? Or you prefer just criticizing, but not spending time answering?

Comment: What a fantastic guy you are! You don't know the answer, then I post one that helps the OP and you downvote me. Thanks a lot for being a great human being!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105652/discussion-between-ed-de-almeida-and-).

Comment: @kfkhalili I edited the answer to show the correct  command. Really sorry. I don't use rbenv, just rvm, and this caused the mistake. Hope it haven't caused any trouble.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida I guess you meant `rbenv local 2.3.0` instead of `rbenv local 2.3.9` in your 3rs step?

Answer (score 1):

Install bundler after installing ruby 2.4.0.

```
gem install bundler
```

If you installed bundler before installing ruby 2.4.0 then you should reinstall bundler or update it.

Also if the above command didn't work.

```
gem update bundler
```