# Your version is 2.3.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Note: This is not a duplicate of [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0). The solution to my question is `bundle update`. The solution to the allegedly duplicate post is `gem update bundler`, which I tried and which did not work. It is a different command. Please remove the duplicate flag.

Rails application. I have looked at these stack posts:

[Your version is 2.3.1 but gemfile specified 2.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311168/your-ruby-version-is-2-3-1-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-4-1-when-running-rails)

[Your version is 2.2.4 but gemfile specified 2.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862231/your-ruby-version-is-2-2-4-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-3-0)

[Your version is 2.0.0 but gemfile specified 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0)

[Your version is 2.3.0 but gemfile specified 2.2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914702/how-to-fix-your-ruby-version-is-2-3-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-2-5-while)

Running `rails s` yields `Your version is 2.3.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1.`

This is easily fixed by changing to `ruby '2.3.4'` in my `Gemfile`, but I would like to use the newer version.

I've run:

```
rvm use ruby-2.4.1

rvm reinstall ruby-2.4.1

gem update bundler

bundle
```

Importantly: `ruby -v` yields `ruby 2.4.1p111`

So, why is it saying my version is `2.3.4`? What am I missing?

EDIT: Please see the answer below. The final step should be `bundle update`.

Comment: you may have a .ruby-version file hanging around there ?

Comment: Does `gem env` offer any insight into what might be wrong?

Comment: That gives a fair amount of information. It says this `RUBY VERSION: 2.4.1 (2017-03-22 patchlevel 111) [x86_64-linux]`, among other things.

Comment: I do have a .ruby-version file. All it says is 2.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last step should be `bundle update` instead of `bundle`:

```
rvm use ruby-2.4.1
bundle update
```

I would not specify ruby in `Gemfile`, I'd rather specify it in `.rvmrc` of rails root, so that ruby version manager reads it; where as `Gemfile` is for gem versions.

Comment: You should be aware that bundle update will update every gem possible, which, depending on how restrictive you set versions in your Gemfile might easily break your application.