# How to fix "Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.5" while server starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am getting this error while running server, how do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if you have already fixed this issue but if not, please read this article . https://makandracards.com/makandra/21545-rbenv-how-to-switch-to-another-ruby-version-temporarily-per-project-or-globally

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0)

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You better install Ruby 2.2.5 for compatibility. The Ruby version in your local machine is different from the one declared in Gemfile.

If you're using [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install):

```
rvm install 2.2.5
rvm use 2.2.5
```

else if you're using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation):

```
rbenv install 2.2.5
rbenv local 2.2.5
```

else if you can not change ruby version by rbenv,
[read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150580/2245697)

Comment: Backward compatibility is not an issue, I think. If it were the opposite (Gemfile specifying 2.3.0 and only 2.2.5 installed) we would have some issues, for sure.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida what if I don't want to change the Gemfile? Like it's a project with multiple people? Or an open-source project

Comment: Then install Ruby 2.2.5, create a private bundle for your app and go ahead, @EmileBergeron.

Comment: These situations are exactly the reasons why I always suggest people to have a separate bundle to each application.

Comment: I was having an issue between the local version of Ruby and the versions of Ruby that Heroku allows. I'm new-ish ro Ruby, Rails, and RVM, so this took me a bit to figure out. Thanks a TON, Tan.

Specifically, no other answer I found in a couple hours of poking around mentioned the rvm use command.

Comment: this caused my mac to ask me to re install rails even though it's already installed "Rails is not currently installed on this system"

Comment: rbenv install - doesn't work, install isn't a supported command.

Comment: I tried the above on rbenv and it didn't work for me. Turns out I was using rvm and not rbenv although both were installed. Make sure you upgrade the right ruby version manager' ruby version

Comment: after having installed it, `rvm use 2.6.1` gives _Required ruby-2.7.0 is not installed._ :) how can I fix this ?

Comment: This may be off topic for some users but I had to do these commands as well. `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` then `bundler update --bundler` ... and then, I could use `rvm use 3.0.0` again, without errors/warnings

Comment: In my case adding correct paths (`$HOME/.rbenv/shims` and `$HOME/.rbenv/bin`) to my .zshrc fixed the problem. Thanks @Tan

Answer (score 71):

If you have already installed 2.2.5 and set as current ruby version, but still showing the same error even if the Ruby version 2.3.0 is not even installed, then just install the bundler.

```
gem install bundler
```

and then:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: This is it right here! Because if you installed bundler before installing and setting your ruby version, calling `bundle check` or `bundle install` will still be referencing the ruby environment that was used for installing `bundler` originally. Cheers!

Comment: Btw, I also had to do `rbenv rehash` after reinstalling bundler.

Comment: Wow, I'd expect a missing gem error message then... anyway, thx!

Comment: @Tarique I still get the same error after running the suggested commands

Comment: @java_geek It's better to install and switch the ruby version (2.2.5) using rvm or rbenv as already suggested by Tan. Also, make sure to change the desired ruby version in the ".ruby-version" file. Thanks.

Comment: I installed v2.7.5 using rvm but was getting the same error. Followed the above command and it worked

Answer (score 49):

If you are using rbenv then make sure that you run the "rbenv rehash" command after you set local or global ruby version. It solved the issue for me.

```
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: `asdf reshim` for asdf users

Comment: @kahcv I ran rbenv rehash but still get the same error

Comment: I realized that you need to close the terminal as well after "bundle install" and "rbenv rehash"

Answer (score 31):

Your **Gemfile** has a line reading

```
ruby '2.2.5'
```

Change it to

```
ruby '2.3.0'
```

Then run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: how to upgrade that? iam already installed railsinstaller from this link https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-3.1.1.exe

Comment: I believe Aptana Studio has a command to update, but I never used it.

Comment: Your suggestion didn't do anything for me, but running `gem update` fixed the error message for me.

Comment: Great that it is all fine now. Really sorry my suggestion didn't help.

Comment: it provide another error 'gem file will remain installed in for inspection. an error occured while installing rjb -v '1.5.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org' succeed before bundling.

Comment: is `.ruby-version` also related  ?

Comment: Yes, @AnthonyKal. .ruby-gemset states the name of the private bundle and .ruby-version the ruby version it will be based on.

Comment: it can break any other gems installed and depends on the newer version.

Answer (score 19):

Had same issue. I'm using `rbenv` and `which ruby` would show the rbenv version:

```
/Users/Mahmoud/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

which bundle though would show:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

After looking in every possible place, turns out my problem was that I needed to update path in `~/.zshrc` in addition to `~/.bash_profile` (where I originally had the changes)

if you're running zsh add those two lines in `~/.zshrc` (or the equivalent file) in addition to `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

After saving, quit terminal and relaunch before retrying. Hopefully this would help.

Comment: I just needed to set `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Not working in my case. I did the same

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. I don't know why this isn't included in the `rbenv` docs. My project is a React Native project, if at all that helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 7):

Two steps worked for me:

```
gem install bundler

bundle install --redownload # Forces a redownload of all gems on the gemfile, assigning them to the new bundler
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem but I solved it by installing the version of the ruby that is specified in my gem file using the RVM

```
    rvm install (ruby version)
```

After the installation, I use the following command to use the the version that you installed.

```
    rvm --default use (ruby version)
```

You have to install bundler by using the following command in order to use the latest version

```
    gem install bundler
```

After the above steps, you can now run following command to install the gems specified on the gemfile

```
    bundle install
```

Answer (score 6):

A problem I had on my Mac using rbenv was that when I first set it up, it loaded a bunch of ruby executables in /usr/local/bin - these executables loaded the system ruby, rather than the current version.

If you run

`which bundle`

And it shows /usr/local/bin/bundle you may have this issue.

Search through /usr/local/bin and delete any files that start with #!/user/bin ruby

Then run

`rbenv rehash`

Answer (score 3):

it can also be in your capistrano config (`Capfile`):

```
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.7.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your **Gemfile**

```
ruby '2.3.0'
```

Comment: How do you access your Gemfile and change this line. Is it a command that should be run? Is it done with a text editor? etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am on Mac OS Sierra. I had to update `/etc/paths` and add `/Users/my.username/.rbenv/shims` to the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some dependency on the version of the Ruby , then install the appropriate version. otherwise change the version in the gemfile in the current directory.

```
rbenv install <required version>
rbenv local <required version>
```

Even after installation it was showing the same error for me, so I just restart the mac, then do the bundle install, it works :)

it should show something like this

```
   <user>@<repo>% rbenv versions 
      system
    * 2.3.7 (set by <app>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing above worked for me.

My issue was : Your Ruby version is 3.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6.

Below Solution worked for me :

1. Open project on VSCode
2. Click around 11th option (=ruby-version) On the left side menu
3. Change the current version to your current version (3.2.1) or whatever your ruby version is.
4. in terminal run command `cd iOS`
5. then run command `bundle install`
6. then run `pod install`
7. Sometimes pod will give error about `installing boost`, so run pod install again, just keep repeating the command until it install everything successfully.

Your app is ready to run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link to install the required version.

https://nrogap.medium.com/install-rvm-in-macos-step-by-step-d3b3c236953b

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
rvm install 2.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

run:

> rbenv global

if old version
then run:
1)

> brew update

> brew install ruby-build
> 2)
> brew install rbenv
> 3)
> rbenv install 2.7.5
> 4)
> rbenv init
> 5)
> rbenv shell 2.7.5
> 6)
> eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"

list commands for rbenv - run simple:

> rbenv

Answer (score 0):

**you can install simple way. Install `rbenv` On macOS with `Homebrew`.**

1. `brew install rbenv ruby-build`
2. `vi ~/.zshrc` // open
3. `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"` // paste it
4. `rbenv install 3.1.2`
5. Close your Terminal window and open a new one so your changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple answer, better for teams with different versions of ruby, I would guess (good for development, maybe for high performance teams this isn't a good idea!).  Change it to

```
ruby ">=2.2.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You better install Ruby 2.2.5 for compatibility. The Ruby version in your local machine is different from the one declared in Gemfile and then run:

rvm use 2.2.5

Comment: There are already better answers than yours posted here. So please do not plagerize contents from others

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was not able to update my ruby version and **rvm** and **rbenv** didnt helped and it created lot of mess in envrionment variables, instead use this below solution, This worked for me:

- `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` or use this link to install Homebrew - https://brew.sh/
- `brew install ruby`
  follow the steps shown in terminal, i.e. echo *path_shown_in_terminal* and source *path_shown_in_terminal*

then just do `ruby -v` to check latest ruby version.

Comment: i am trying this on Mac M1 system, Monterey OS

Answer (score -1):

For `$` Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1. 
      Changed 2.4.1 in Gemfile to 2.3.0

Answer (score -1):

I install rvm and rbenv it not help me so i go the project and open Gemfile change the ruby version with recommend version and than follow the command cd  ios -> bundle install

Your project is ready to Run now.

Answer (score -1):

Open Gemfile and find
ruby '2.2.5'

Change it to

ruby '2.3.0'

then install bundle