# How to change line in gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I want to change ruby `2.3.5` line in gemfile to ruby `2.4.2`
but i did not know how?

[image]

Comment: Gemfile.lock >> command not found

Comment: Have you tried this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37914702/7387742

Comment: i want to work with ruby 2.4.2 , so i can not lacal 2.3.5 by rvm or rbenv

Comment: Your question is unclear. You don't know how to edit a file? Then how are you going to write programs?

Answer (score 0):

inside your working folder there is file .ruby-version, change the content from 2.3.5 to 2.4.2 and then run steps below, if you working with rbenv

```
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
ruby -v 
# make sure it said 2.4.2
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open your `Gemfile` in a text editor and change the

```
ruby '2.3.5'
```

to

```
ruby '2.4.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your `Gemfile` and update ruby version `ruby '2.4.2'` Then you will need to go to terminal and install that version if not already installed. Use `rvm use 2.4.3` (if you are using rvm) command to select 2.4.3 version.