# How to find out where ruby version that rails points to is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I have only ruby-2.3.7 in my machine and the output of the `rvm list rubies` is

```
=* ruby-2.3.7 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

but when i try to do `rails s` I get an error saying `Your Ruby version is 2.6.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.7`

I'm not sure how to find out where this particular version of ruby exists in the machine and how to uninstall it or make this error go away.

I cannot change the version of ruby being used in the gemfile though.

Edit.

The output of `which ruby` is `/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/bin/ruby`

the output of `bundle env` is

```
Bundler             1.17.3
  Platforms         ruby, x86_64-darwin-18
Ruby                2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-darwin18]
  Full Path         /Users/bennetsunder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/bin/ruby
  Config Dir        /Users/bennetsunder/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/etc
RubyGems            3.0.6
  Gem Home          /Users/bennetsunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7
  Gem Path          /Users/bennetsunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7:/Users/bennetsunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7@global
  User Path         /Users/bennetsunder/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  Bin Dir           /Users/bennetsunder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/bin
Tools               
  Git               2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)
  RVM               1.29.8 (latest)
  rbenv             not installed
  chruby            not installed
  rubygems-bundler  (1.4.5)
```

Comment: What is the output of `which ruby` in your terminal?

Comment: By any chance is there a value set for the environment variable `BUNDLER_SPEC_RUBY_VERSION`? You can verify this in the terminal with the command `echo $BUNDLER_SPEC_RUBY_VERSION`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.5" while server starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914702/how-to-fix-your-ruby-version-is-2-3-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-2-5-while)

Comment: `bundle env` gives you a lot of info about the bundler environment. At the beginning of the very copious output it tells you about the ruby version it's using. Check it's the one that is managed by rvm.

Comment: @Hamed there is no value set for that command. its just prints and empty line

Comment: @LesNightingill bundle env points to 2.3.7 I can't see where 2.6.4 is on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I had installed ruby-2.6.4 view brew and it was on the path. To fix this you either do `brew uninstall ruby` and work with the one installed via `rvm` or remove the path entry which fetches from brew installation directory.