# error Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5

Tags: ruby, bundle, npx

This happens when I run `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`.

When I check the system ruby version with `ruby -v`, it is already 2.7.5. `ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-darwin21]`. Anyone has any idea for this problem?

Comment: Do you still have a 2.6.8 hanging around on your system, which npx accidentally might pick up?

Comment: I tried uninstall 2.6.8 with `rvm remove ruby-2.6.8` and got `ruby-2.6.8 - #already gone Using /Users/jiayuli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5`, but still got the same error.@user1934428

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.5" while server starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914702/how-to-fix-your-ruby-version-is-2-3-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-2-5-while)

Comment: Not really, I referred to this question before.@ChaseMcDougall

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I suggest that you search where you have a 2.6.8.  As a first start - if you are lucky, it may save you time - I would do a `type -a ruby`, and if this does not bring up something of interest, I would start a `find` over the whole filesystem, and get myself a bottle of wine, until the _find_ is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you’re using [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) to manage Ruby versions.
You need to install and run the correct version, not delete the current.

Something like

```
rvm install 2.7.5
rvm use 2.7.5
```

Comment: This is exactly how I installed and used 2.7.5 on my laptop, after this I still got the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### The Gemfile Isn't (Directly) Your Issue

The Gemfile is irrelevant to solving this issue. It's just triggering it because your in-project Ruby version isn't matching what RubyGems (via the `Gemfile` or `Gemfile.lock`) expects as a constraint. It could be a minimum version, an exact version, an approximate version, and so forth. There are a lot of ways to specify version constraints in a project, and the Gemfile is just where the constraint-related exception is being raised by Bundler.

You could possibly make the problem go away simply by removing the requirement for a later version of Ruby from the Gemfile or gemspec, removing the Gemfile.lock, and re-running Bundler. However, if your code relies on features in a later version this will just create other problems for you. You really ought to uncover what's changing your Ruby environment within the project directory.

### Dotfiles

There are a lot of reasons this could happen, but if your system Ruby is 2.7.5, then you need to check your project directory for various dotfiles like:

1. `.ruby-version`
2. `.rvmrc`
3. `~/.rvmrc`
4. `.envrc`
5. `.env`

or various other files that affect your shell environment or whatever Ruby version manager you're using. Most Ruby version managers respect `.ruby-version`, but some version managers use other files, including defaults or shims that may be set elsewhere. IDE's also often have their own project-specific configuration files, too, and they can sometimes be set to override the project's standard settings.

Also, make sure to check your `Gemfile.lock` and `*.gemspec` in addition to the Gemfile itself, in case something is being specified there or constrained by some other dependency.

#### Inspecting Environment Variables

You should also look at the Ruby- and RubyGems-related environment variables from your project directory to see how various values are set within the project. For example:

```bash
printenv | grep -E '^(RUBY|GEM)' | sort
```

### Shebang Lines

In addition, you should check your shebang lines in any executable Ruby or shell scripts you're relying on to see whether a specific non-system Ruby is being invoked. For example:

```bash
grep -Enr '^#.*ruby' *.rb | grep -F '.rb:1:'
```

will find all the shebang lines that properly appear on the first line of a Ruby file. This will either point to a specific Ruby like `#!/usr/bin/ruby` or might be using a *PATH* lookup with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.

Shell scripts might be harder to inspect, as there may be calls to other executables or even an `exec` command, so you'll need to be more liberal with your grepping if you are looking for an interpreter call further down than the shebang line.

#### Checking *PATH* Order

In the case of `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, you should inspect your *PATH* environment variable to see why the Ruby you want isn't being called first. Using `which -a ruby` (if supported by your OS) will show you all rubies in your *PATH* in the order they would be invoked by the shell. It's possible that you're simply calling an unexpected Ruby version that comes first in the *PATH*.