# Ruby version error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, rvm, gemfile

I'm using RVM with my `2.3.1@market` gemset and getting error while trying to run my specs saying that

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

So I added `ruby '2.3.1'` to my Gemfile but I'm still getting error that I need `2.0.0' anyway. I've also tried to reinstall bundler, which didn't help.

**UPD:** When I'm specifying any version than `ruby '2.3.1'` this line isn't ignored. For example if `ruby '2.1.2'` is specified then I'm getting error that

```
 Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
```

but when I'm specifying `ruby '2.3.1'` I'm getting

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0)

Comment: @Sharj no, because in my issue `ruby '2.3.1` is spicified in my Gemfile, while I'm still getting error that I need 2.0.0. So this line  is ignored by some reason while in that question all right with this.

Answer (score 0):

try running

`gem install bundler`

or

`gem update bundler`

this may solve your problem

if that doesn't help then please check `ruby -v` for you project and make sure that you have `ruby 2.3.1` installed for that you can use `rvm install 2.3.1` and make if default to your project by `echo 2.3.1 > .ruby-version`

Comment: bundler is up to date, `ruby 2.3.1` is installed and specifying 2.3.1 in .ruby-version didn't help.