# Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv, asdf-vm

I keep getting this error

`Your Ruby version is 2.5.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1`

I use rbenv and homebrew.   I also realized that I have .asdf working.

Based on other Stackoverflow, I have tried:

`` 2.5.0 % rbenv local 2.5.1
rbenv: version `2.5.1' not installed
2.5.0 % ruby -v
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin16] ``

When i run this command, i get this:

`2.5.0 .rbenv % gem env home
/Users/annxxxx/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0`

UPDATE:

So all the commands related to Homebrew are not working because it seems my system seems to be looking for ruby in the .asdf file (this version of ruby was 2.5.0) is pointing using .asdf

I updated .asdf to now use 2.5.1 (so now working - but my machine now has multiple copies of 2.5.1)

My conclusion is that I have multiple copies of ruby on my machine. 
 - one set for rbenv/homebrew
 - one set for .asdf

Question:
1- should i have both of these?
2- I would prefer to remove .asdf ?
a- how do i do that?
b- once I do that, what do I need to do to get rbenv/homebrew working?

Comment: Do you have 2.5.1 installed? Did you try `rbenv install 2.5.1` ?

Comment: you should try to update bundler as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039832/1657377

Comment: Yes - install is there..
```
rbenv install 2.5.1
rbenv: /Users/annieogrady/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1 already exists
```

Comment: I have tried both of the above recommendations.  

The issue i think is this:  http://take.ms/x0hgt

how/where can i get to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use several version managers, you end up having several versions of everything. `asdf` installs in `~/.asdf/installs/ruby/*`, `chruby` *reads* from `~/.rubies` (where `ruby-install` installs them), `RVM` installs in `~/.rvm/rubies`, `rbenv` in `~/.rbenv/versions` and `rbfu` in `~/.rbfu/rubies`.

You need to decide on one version manager and configure it so it accepts your projects' configs.

You might go with `asdf`, set it up so it reads `.ruby-version` (see https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby#ruby-version-file), and remove all the others -- also, make sure you bundle your dependencies inside each project, otherwise you will get a very messy global.

To help with the transition, set up a shell alias for your old version manager (for instance in bash, add `alias rbenv="echo 'Use ASDF instead'"` to your shell init file -- permutate the "old version manager" and "new version manager" names as needed)