# Your Ruby version is 2.5.1 but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error

> Your Ruby version is 2.5.1 but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0

How can i fix this or atleast upgrade Ruby on Gemfile.

Comment: does your gemfile have ruby version specified ? then just change the version :)

Comment: Do you have 2.4.0 installed? If not, do it and then try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `ruby '2.4.0'` line in your `Gemfile` somewhere. Change it to `ruby '2.5.1'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your app's Ruby version is `'2.4.0'` whereas the installed Ruby version on your system is `'2.5.1'`.

If your application should be running in `'2.4.0'` then install then run `rvm install 2.4.0`.

If it's okay to upgrade your app's Ruby version, change `ruby '2.4.0'` to `ruby '2.5.1'` in you `Gemfile`.

Hope this helped.