# How to fix 'Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.2'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I got an error: `Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.2` with running `bundle install`.

Besides, `ruby -v` shows `ruby 2.5.2p104 (2018-10-18 revision 65133) [x86_64-linux]`.

OS: Debian 9

Problem with bundler was solved with: [Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0)

But now there is the same error with `rails s`

Comment: the next problem is with `rails s`

Comment: Check the version mentioned in your Gemfile.lock

Comment: cannot find any ruby version in Gemfile.lock

Comment: Do you have a `.ruby-version` file in your project @Vadym?

Comment: yes, it appeared after ruby reinstallation

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by,

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.5.2
rvm default use ruby-2.5.2
bundle install
bin/rails s
```