# How to fix “Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.7p206”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I search for some answers related to this question but didn't get a particular answer. 
I checked my ruby version.
 Ruby -v gives  2.5.7p206 as a result and in gem file also add ruby '2.5.7p206'.

In gemfile.lock it show

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.7p206

So I didn't find where the actual problem.

thank you.

Comment: Maybe 2 version of ruby are installed?

Comment: try to reuse this answer with your version of ruby https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087270/4251975

Comment: Hi @vishal aher.. If u are using rubymine please check at `Languages & Frameworks > Ruby SDK and Gems`. May be there will be the ruby version 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

1. First install RVM(ruby version manager) after installing
2. run rvm install x.x.x to install a specific version. (in place of x.x.x 2.5.7)
   3.Use rvm use x.x.x --default to change your default Ruby(in your case 2.5.7)
   if you are using using ubuntu it will work.
   you can follow these steps from this link too https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/nginx/oss/install_language_runtime.html