# Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

```sh
ruby -v

ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]

cat Gemfile.lock | grep -A 2 RUBY

RUBY VERSION

   ruby 2.7.1p83

bundle platform --ruby

ruby 2.7.1p83

sudo rake db:create

Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1
```

I can't see what is the problem here. This is a fresh installation of Ubuntu it's 20.04 and I was trying to set up a ruby on rails env for the first time.

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` to run rake tasks. Try a simple `bundle exec rake db:create`

Comment: Have you tried the solution for another ruby versions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different users can have different versions of ruby installed.

When you run `ruby -v` you will see the version of ruby in your user environment.

When you run `sudo rake ...` (or sudo anything) you will use the version of ruby in the super user’s environment.

In short, don’t use sudo. `bundle exec rake db:migrate` Will ensure you’re using the same version of ruby as you see in the output of  `bundle platform —ruby`

To help understand what’s happening when you try to check the version, try `sudo ruby -v`   That should be where v2.7.0 comes from

Comment: Now I see, in return I got an access denied message because I didn't include a password in database.yml. It workey