# Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I followed this guide to deploy my rails app: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/20.04#ruby
Everything works fine except i would like to use rails console on the server i deployed my app, and i can't because of this message :

```
Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.0
```

If i `ruby -v` with my deploy user, here is the answer `ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux`

But if i `sudo ruby -v`, here is the answer `ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`. So i guess, that's where it comes from (as said in [Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389352/your-ruby-version-is-2-7-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-7-1))...

Has anyone an idea of how i could do ?

Edit : here is my deployment script, as deploy user

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-vars.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-vars
exec $SHELL
rbenv install 3.0.0
rbenv global 3.0.0
gem install bundler
```

Comment: What does `gem env` say?

Comment: If you're using RVM or rbenv then it's possible that your root user is not properly engaging that variant. RVM has `rvmsudo` specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @tadman :`RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.0.0 (2020-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: i am using rbenv

Comment: `sudo` does load an entirely different shell which can drop your local Ruby version settings. You shouldn't deploy as `root`, and `sudo` shouldn't be a factor. You can always `bundle install --path=.bundle` to avoid having to `sudo` at all.

Comment: i don't deploy as root

Comment: Are you saying `rails c` on the deployment target causes this error but when you run `ruby -v` in the exact same location you get `3.0.0`? e.g. `ssh deployment_user@deployment_target; cd path/to/rails/app; ruby -v # 3.0.0; rails c #ERROR` ?

Comment: @engineersmnky : exactly :-(

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal

```
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile
```

this will solve your problem [Reference](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite)